# ArcGIS toScreenPoint not working

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I have a lat / long and I'm trying to convert that point to a screen point (the pixel location on the current map). Current version of arcgis-js-api: "3.24.0". Here is my implementation:

```
var point = new Point(track.geometry.coordinates, map.spatialReference); // 4326 spatial reference
return ScreenUtils.toScreenPoint(map.extent, map.width, map.height, point);
```

sometimes the screen point will display the correct location, then if you pan around the world it no longer has the correct pixel location. Or if I have two points across the IDL then one is in the correct location and the other is not.